# Inline Data for a Theory doesn't track changes in R# runner

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, resharper, xunit.net

I have an Unit Tests like that

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("1")]
public void Should_Fail_Because_Blabla(string value)
{
  var success =  MyClass.MyStaticMethod(value)
  Asset.False(success, "bla bla");
}
```

I'm Using VS 2017, xUnit 2.3.1 on a .net core 2.1 assembly and also have R# 2018.1.2 installed.

When I change the the Value of the InlineData, the Data isn't updated in the
"Unit Test Sessions" window of the R# and running the test, does it with the outdated data.

However if I comment / uncomment the InlineData, works.

Any Idea how to fix the issue, so t hat the actual inline data is taken alsways into considreation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I've found, this is a bug in resharper, fortunately it has been reported on here:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-470119

so hopefully it will be fixed in the next resharper update.